# The code works but cat() doesn't print any line

Tags: r

I am trying to change a boolean value to false when a numeric value is negative.

```
    z = c(23,34,-9, -10)
    negative.count = 0
    for(i in length(z)){
      ab = TRUE
      if(z[i] < 0){
        ab = FALSE
        negative.count += 1
      }
      if(ab) cat("The value", i, "is", z[i])
    }
```

Now I don;t get any error. But, I also don't get any output; nothing gets printed.

Comment: The command `+=1` does not work in R.

Comment: The error is gone now but cat() doesn't print anything.

Comment: In R, I would use the following expressions to achieve the same results without for loop: `negative.count <- sum(z < 0)` which returns `2` and `idx <- which(z<0); sprintf("The value %i is %i", idx, z[idx])` which returns `[1] "The value 3 is -9"  "The value 4 is -10"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `+=1` does not work in R

2) `i in length(z)` runs from 4 to 4,....use `1:length(z)`

3) use `paste()` to concatenate strings

```
z = c(23,34,-9, -10)
negative.count = 0
for(i in 1:length(z)){
  ab = TRUE
  if(z[i] < 0){
    ab = FALSE
    negative.count = negative.count + 1
  }
  if(ab) cat("The value", i, "is", z[i], "\n")
}
```

I think some tutorials could help to adapt your programming skills to R.

Comment: no need for `paste` inside `cat` though `\n` in the end of the string could help...

Comment: thx, i didnt know, I will edit.

Comment: I guess I was too much rushing. Just after you pointed out the problem in for(i in 1:length(z)), I noticed it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, the issue is resolved @BigDataScientist